# COUNTIF based on three conditions using OFFSET and MATCH

Tags: match, spreadsheet, offset, countif

[Please see example screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q2KJ.jpg)

I would like to populate cell M2. Firstly to match K2 (Taylor) against column headers C1:I1 looking at the results in the column C2:C32. I would like to find the amount of times "a" appears in C2:C32 where Type (Column B) = "r".

So the result would be 3 (Reynolds, Maggio & Hamilton).

As you can see I've managed to populate Column R with totals without comparing against Type (Column B) but am having great difficulty understanding how to extend the comparison, intentionally without the use of helper columns/rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "managed to populate Column R with totals without comparing against Type (Column B)" <-- can you please share the formula for this..

Comment: Hi. The formula in R2 was: =COUNTA(OFFSET($B$1,1,MATCH($K2,$C$1:$I$1,0),32,1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to depend on 2 columns, you will have to use `COUNTIFS`. Without being dynamic, the formula for M2 would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$32,"r",$C$2:$C$32,"a")
          ^------------^ ^------------^
           1st Condition  2nd Condition
```

To make it dynamic, only the second column needs to be changed:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$32,"r",OFFSET($B$2:$B$32,0,MATCH($K2,$C$1:$I$1,0)),"a")
```

---

Your total's formula could be simplified to this also (keep the range as it is instead of manually putting it as 32 rows high for instance):

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET($B$2:$B$32,0,MATCH($K2,$C$1:$I$1,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry that is brilliant.

Comment: @topstuff you may accept the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It'll remove this question from SU 'unanswered' list. ( :